# Thousand separator Jinja2

Tags: templates, format, numbers, jinja2, asciidoc

I trying to print a variable in an AsciiDoc using Jinja2 template and I do not find the way to print this number using a thousand separator (space or dot). This number came as text and I format it to float, then I print it with the decimals I want, but in addition to that, I want to print it with a thousand separator. This is how I do:

```
### dc_max_avg_memory_usage.json.data.result[0].value[1] = 12345.6789

{{ '%0.0f'| format(dc_max_avg_memory_usage.json.data.result[0].value[1]|float) }}
```

This prints me the number as `12345.67` but I want it like `12 345,67` or `12.345,67`

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Jinja2's `format` filter uses `printf`-style format strings. See https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#format

Python's `format` function has more features, and can use the comma as a grouping operator. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

In Python, you can:

```py
print('{:,.2f}'.format(12345.6789))
```

To be able to use Python's `format` in a Jinja template, you have to create a custom filter:

```py
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment()

def commafy(value):
    """Applies thousands separator to floats, with 2 decimal places."""
    return '{:,.2f}'.format(float(value))

env.filters['commafy'] = commafy

template_string = """{{ mynum | commafy }}"""
template = env.from_string(template_string)
print(template.render(mynum='12345.6789'))
```

Comment: You can use it directly inside the Jinja templates. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python string formatter inside a Jinja template. This is an example code:

```
{{ "{:0,.2f}".format(price) }}
```

Regards!